# Are "plants" and "animals" inevitable on an alien planet?

Tags: biology, aliens, creature-design

Is it simply inevitable that on a planet organisms would split into motile and non-motile groups? I'm planning on creating slime-like amoebic chemotrophs for my light devoid-planet that are the "plant" equivalent to earth. Is it improbable that none of these creatures become tree-like in nature and remain somewhat motile?

Comment: Plants that live in places devoid of light tend to have black leaves to maximise absorption of infrared. My only tip for you.

Comment: Sounds a bit like you're describing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physarum_polycephalum to me, which would be an interesting concept ot expand on.

Comment: The basic reason why multi-cellular plants are not mobile is that they'd need a lot of surface area to collect enough energy to move around.  So one could imagine chemosynthetic plant analogues that cluster around hydrothermal vents, and animal analogues that travel between vents looking for "plants" to eat.

Comment: Not all animals are motile. Nor all all plants sessile. Plants just tend to be due to energy considerations.

Comment: if there are mobile plants (which do exist) it is more like a 1 inch per hour crawl. i believe there was a fungi like that. but that's not really a plant. there are plants that have mouths that close and opens, and plants that change direction based on the sun but not much. this covers the most of plant movement. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapid_plant_movement

Comment: There would be no trees. That shape is adapted primarily to maximize photosynthetic surface area. Grow tall to get above competitors, unfurl branches with leaves to grab as much sunlight as possible.

Answer (score 14):

Every organism needs energy of some sort to survive. There are two basic strategies: go to where the energy is or wait for it to come to you. Both have advantages depending on how plentiful and mobile said energy source is, especially when you consider competition and predation, so it's reasonable to assume you'd find both.

Keep in mind that once you have life, for every energy source, something *will* eventually evolve to eat it, because doing so gives a competitive advantage over things that can't. And that thing, in turn, becomes a potential energy source for something else. Lather, rinse, repeat.

For instance, your chemotrophs may be harvesting chemical energy welling up from ocean fissures, which doesn't benefit from moving (except maybe spores sent off to land in other fissures), but it's inevitable that something will come along that eats the chemotrophs, and it will likely need to keep moving from fissure to fissure or it will eat one clean and then starve to death.

Answer (score 3):

No, it’s not improbable at all. Evolution is driven by selective pressures, such as access to energy. Trees evolved to get tall so that way they could get more sunlight than their competitors, there is no particular reason why chemeotrophs would have selective pressure to grow tall like a tree. After all, the chemeotroph’s food is probably on the ground or in a hydrothermal vent

Comment: OP seems to be focused on the motility of the different classes of organisms, rather than the height.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might want to think more in terms of ecological niches - usually an organism evolves into a certain form because it is profitable to do so. There is space in the ecosystem for it, and so fitting into that role will be rewarding.

If you want there to be no trees on your world, you'd want there to be a reason why trees don't exist. Perhaps large herbivores with powerful jaws evolved quite rapidly and so ate anything resembling a trunk, therefore "trees" never really came into being and instead you'll find shrubbery.

---

Also, "plants and animals" is quite a reductive way of viewing our ecosystems. You might want to research other life forms - like fungi, which are present in a lot of different forms - and the variations within these categories of life. Mosses and algae are plants, so is grass, and so are trees, but these each fit very different ecological niches.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider a lot of aquatic life belonging to the animalia realm, a majority is fixed on the benthos. The main issue is that to grow big, you need to have tissues to support yourself. For plants on Earth it's deadcells and it's calcium for corals as examples.

To grow big, you chemotrophs need to excrete something 'useless' to help them keeping their form.

Answer (score 0):

Trees evolved to have more access to light, as a taller plant can cover a smaller plant, and remove its competition. Without light, this strategy doesn't work, and so these chemotrophs will most likely not evolve to become trees